# Django2.0: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, django, utf-8

While i install Django 2.0 in windows 10, and use command 
    python manage.py runserver

Get below errors, and the localhost:8000 can't be opened

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
December 06, 2017 - 10:50:09
Django version 2.0, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x0000011FCC05AB70>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 142, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 163, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: i have found the pc name had been changed in zh-cn, i've modified it to en, then it works without error